# UnsatisfiedLinkError using jcurses

Tags: java, eclipse, libraries, jcurses

I'm trying to make a program that uses jcurses as an external library. Every time the program runs and tries to use Toolkit, I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   C:\Users\freelix2000\AppData\Local\Temp\libjcurses.dll: Can't load IA
>   32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
>           at jcurses.system.NativeLibrary.load(NativeLibrary.java:18)
>           at jcurses.system.Toolkit.(Toolkit.java:36)
>           at ascii3d.Main.main(Main.java:14)

I'm kind of new to importing external libraries, so I have no clue what this means. I just grabbed a jcurses .jar from the internet and imported it in Eclipse.